# Set Silex 2 application locale in a service controller from route

Tags: silex

How can I get the locale from the route and use it in the service controller?

Here is my service controller:

```
$app['clients.controller'] = function() use ($app) {
    $clientTranslator = new ClientTranslator;
    $translations = $clientTranslator->getTranslations();
    foreach ($translations as $domain => $data) {
        foreach ($data as $locale => $messages) {
            $app['translator']->addResource('array', $messages, $locale, $domain);
        }
    }
    $app['translator']->setLocale($app['locale']);
    return new ClientController($app, $app['clients.model'], $app['clients.validator']);
};
```

Notice that I am trying to set the translator locale from the app locale.

And here are the routes calling this service controller:

```
$app->mount ( '/en', function ($client) use ($app) {
    $app ['locale'] = "en";
    $client->match ( '/{id}/edit', 'clients.controller:editAction')
        ->assert ( 'id', '\d+' )
        ->method ( 'GET|POST' );
    $client->match ( '/add', 'clients.controller:addAction')
        ->method ( 'GET|POST' );
    $client->match ( '/{id}', 'clients.controller:deleteAction' )
        ->assert ( 'id', '\d+' )
        ->method ( 'DELETE' );
    $client->get('/', "clients.controller:indexAction");
});
$app->mount('/fr', function ($client) use ($app) {
    $app['locale'] = "fr";
    $client->match ( '/{id}/edit', 'clients.controller:editAction')
        ->assert ( 'id', '\d+' )
        ->method ( 'GET|POST' );
    $client->match ( '/add', 'clients.controller:addAction' )
        ->method ( 'GET|POST' );
    $client->match ( '/{id}', 'clients.controller:deleteAction' )
        ->assert ( 'id', '\d+' )
        ->method ( 'DELETE' );
    $client->get ( '/', "clients.controller:indexAction" );
} );
```

What is happening now is that the app locale is always French. I understand now that the statements in the mount section are executed even if that route is not called.

What would be the right way to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The right way for the routes in this case is as follows

```
$app->mount ( '{_locale}/', function ($client) use ($app) {
    $client->match ( '/{id}/edit', 'clients.controller:editAction')
        ->assert ( 'id', '\d+' )
        ->method ( 'GET|POST' );
    $client->match ( '/add', 'clients.controller:addAction')
        ->method ( 'GET|POST' );
    $client->match ( '/{id}', 'clients.controller:deleteAction' )
        ->assert ( 'id', '\d+' )
        ->method ( 'DELETE' );
    $client->get('/', "clients.controller:indexAction");
});
```

This way the locale is automatically set.